# Unable to archive HDFS data

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, archive

I am trying  to archive HDFS data into a folder located at the path `/archives` using the command given below:

```
hadoop archive -archiveName zoo3.har -p /temp/test -r 3 /archives
```

But I get the following error:

> File /archives/zoo3.har/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1498217315045_0006_m_000000_2/part-0
>   could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). 
>   There are 6 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this
>   operation.

Cluster Configuration:

1. 6 Data Nodes (all active)
2. Each with 5 TB disk and 64 GB RAM
3. HDP - 2.4

Comment: did you check if there is enough disk space?

Comment: Yes, the disk space is sufficient and the data that I am trying to archive is less than 500 MB.